# Cannot boot my Ubuntu after Upgrading it

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, recovery-mode

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I went to do some cleaning... So the system lock.

Then I tried to log back in. It wouldn't let me.

Then I forced Ubuntu to go into the terminal.

Then I tried login in with root but I couldn't.

Then I force a reboot.

Now I cannot start Ubuntu.

I get this (it's flashing... I was lucky to capture it):

[image]

So I tried:

[image]

Then selected:

> dpkg         Repair broken packages

Then I selected `Resume`.

Then I got this:

[image]

Is there some way to repair this without re-installing Ubuntu?

This happened 3 or 4 weeks ago.